# PHP: How do I can access .js and .csss in Web dir from my Module in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, css, module, yii2

I've an application build in Yii2 framework, and I've develop the application in *backend side*, but know I want to copy them become a module.

#### This my application dir

```
backend
--modules
  --pstk
    --controllers
      --ValidationController.php
      --DefaultController.php
      --InterviewController.php
      --StudentController.php
      --SiteController.php
      --UsersController.php
    --models
      --Validation.php
      --Interview.php
      --Student.php
      --Users.php
    --views
      --validation
        --_form.php
        --view.php
        --index.php
        --update.php
        --create.php
      --interview
      --student
      --users
    --Module.php
--web
  --css
    --manual_general.css
  --js
    --upload_header.js
  --style
```

For example I've successfully run `view.php` from the module in browser, but the module can't access the `.css` and `.js` from `backend/web/`.
So the view displayed, but it's view mashed-up and all button didn't do any action when clicked.

#### Anyone know why the module didn't access the `manual_general.css` and `upload_header.js` from `backend/web/`? and how I can solve this problem?

Any help, will be appreciated. Thanks :)

#### EDITED:

This is the code in mi view.php to connect to `.js` and `.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../web/css/manual_general.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../web/js/upload_header.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try using yii\helpers\Url::to.  Example: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= Url::to('@web/css/manual_general.css') ?>">

Comment: @sonofagun I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: SOLVED! Big thanks to @sonofagun :D

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I'll enter it as an answer - please mark it correct.

Comment: @sonofagun Done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using yii\helpers\Url::to, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= Url::to('@web/css/manual_general.css') ?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= Url::to('@web/js/upload_header.js') ?>"></script>
```

Alternatively, in view.php you may do (assuming $this is your View instance):

```
<?php $this->registerCssFile('@web/css/manual_general.css'); ?>
<?php $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/upload_header.js'); ?>
```